# Hibernate is not saving H2 schema

Tags: hibernate, h2

I'm using Hibernate to manage a small file-based H2 database fully, letting it create the schema and all. I'm just using a simple class to populate the database and print what it saved to the console and that works fine. But if I try to pull results from anything else (another class) the database is empty except for the H2-created information. So the database file is being created fine, but the schema creation does not seem to work and no information stays in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your database URL? The problem might be related to this: http://h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files

Comment: Thanks, the problem was me appending the .h2.db extension when trying to view it and creating a whole new empty database.